# React - Render page after props receive new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have few divs in my page and I want to display the latest data in them getting from an API after every 15 sec without showing the refresh of the page.

The issue is **this.props** have latest data but its not rendering on the page. Do I need to use **componentWillUpdate** ? or **componentWillReceiveProps** ? as both of them are obsolete.

How can I make sure to get the latest data on the page after every 15 sec.

```
    componentDidMount(){
        this.updateTimer = setInterval(() => this.getData(), 15000);
    }

    getData = e => {

        const _this = this 
        admin.getDataFromAPI()
            .then((response) => {
                if(_this.props.getData.error){
                    this.context.store.dispatch(receivedDataFromAPI(response));
                }
                else if(_this.props.getData.data){
                    let updatedData = response.data;
                    let oldData = _this.props.getData.data;
                    oldData.map((col, i) => {
                        col.state = updatedData[i].state;
                        col.name = updatedData[i].name;
                        col.xValue = updatedData[i].xValue;
                    })   
                }
            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                this.context.store.dispatch(failedDataFromAPI(error));
            });
    };

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.updateTimer);
    }
```

Comment: You can't imperatively change the props within the component, you'd have to do it in the parent component and let the new props be passed down, then they will automatically re-render when they're updated. You could pass down a callback that will change the parent state, or run the update in the parent itself, or update the store as it looks like you're using one.

Comment: use a state rather. state changes are immediately reflected whereas props are constants. they aren't meant to change after rendered.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways of doing this

1. Using props you can tell parent to send different props which will cause rerender. I personally do not recommend this for sake of complexity.
2. Use states. Using states is really easy and I will show it to you in this example:

import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
class Results extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       results : [] //Your empty array or initial value that you set
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
     //Here you can set interval which will make requests to API and wait for answers
     //once you get response you do : 
     this.setState({
          results : responseFromAjax
      });
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
  }


  render(){

    return(
     <p>{this.state.results}</p>
    )
  }

}

export default Results;
```

In constructor of the Class Component you set its state which is basically JSON.
Once you want to change the value that is being displayed, you just call `this.setState` function and it pass the updated key:value pair which will replace the ones that are currently active.